# T SQL Count and Group by calculable column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

This code

```
DECLARE @SNH TABLE 
(
    cntDATE date, 
    cntQUEUE varchar(10),
    [cntINKTONERBLACK] int
)
INSERT INTO @SNH (cntDATE, cntQUEUE, [cntINKTONERBLACK])
VALUES ('2001-04-04', 'Queue01', 3),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue01', 1),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue01', 100)
SELECT TOP 5
    [cntQUEUE] AS cntqueue,
    [cntdate],
    [cntINKTONERBLACK],
    (CASE 
         WHEN LAG(cntinktonerblack) OVER (PARTITION BY cntqueue ORDER BY cntqueue, cntdate) < cntinktonerblack
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0
     END) AS signalcolumn
FROM 
    @SNH
WHERE 
    [cntINKTONERBLACK] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    cntqueue, cntDATE ASC
```

gives the following table

| cntqueue | cntdate | cntINKTONERBLACK | signalcolumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Queue01 | 2001-04-04 | 3 | 0 |
| Queue01 | 2001-04-05 | 1 | 0 |
| Queue01 | 2001-04-06 | 100 | 1 |

Is there a way to count '1' in signal column and group 1st column to have?

| cntqueue | NumberOfJumps |
| --- | --- |
| Queue01 | 1 |

Comment: What do the results have to do with the data you have shown?  I'm confused.

Comment: Data has over 64k rows. 1st column is a name of a queue and the 4th column is calculated to have either 1 or 0. Result is a list uniquely grouped by 1st column and sum of the 4th. Now it's pivoted in Excel but I'd rather have it directly in SQL

Comment: Side point: partitioning and ordering by the same column doesn't really make sense, you probably want `PARTITION BY cntqueue ORDER BY cntdate`

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select cntqueue, sum(signalcolumn)
from (select cntQUEUE, 
             (case when lag(cntinktonerblack) over (partition by cntqueue order by cntqueue, cntdate) < cntinktonerblack
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as signalcolumn
      from [watchdocstatsSU].[dbo].[queuescounters] 
      where [cntINKTONERBLACK] is NOT null
     ) q
group by cntqueue
order by cntqueue;
```

Comment: Gordon, you are, you are ... you are very good! It works, thank you so much!